# Azure - Shared Access Signature with Social Media sharing

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am in a situation where I have few terabytes of data on azure blobs. I have recently added SAS (shared access signature) functionality while returning the direct blob urls back to client and added an expiry date of 2 minutes for all the images coming out. So, now the resource is guaranteed the read access for 2 minutes and expires after it.

All good up to now. I also have social media buttons to share my content to facebook, google+ or twitter etc. When a user shares the content to facebook lets say, the thumbnail remains with the link for specified time but expires after that time giving a bad user experience.

The example of URL generated is

```
 https://storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/images/2016-May-23-03-28-56_14.jpg?sv=2015-07-08&sr=c&sig=LENHRuvX1Q1d8r2DCJTdMp6fB8mv82DJsMAN8ZAM3C4%3D&se=2016-06-14T22%3A55%3A37Z&sp=r
```

I want to ask if there is any way out to avoid this situation? I don't have a clue right now.

Comment: I'm confused by the question: If you're using private blobs, and providing access via SAS, then access will expire. If you want permanent access, you either have to give it an infinite access policy or have a public blob. What, specifically , are you asking?

Comment: I wanted to keep using private blobs for short intervals of times (depending upon the average user stay on the page) via SAS but somehow find a way to maintain the thumbnails that have been shared with the links on social media like facebook. This sounds confusing I know, all i wanted to know was if there's some way i could achieve this even after blob expires.

Comment: I think I will have to change the policy to infinite access! I am not using any user authentication on my site so all my data was public! Just because of social media sharing (broken image after it is expired), the real purpose of SAS might become useless!

Comment: Can you create a dedicate public access container just for these thumbnails? If this is not feasible, another option I can think about is using SAS with stored access policy so that you can setup a longer expire time and control the access by using the policy as described at - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/#controlling-a-sas-with-a-stored-access-policy